# Mi archivo CSS no está funcionando como debería cuando hago Publish

Tags: html, css

Digo que mi archivo CSS no está funcionando como deberá ya que cuando ejecuto la aplicacion en debug o localmente, funciona perfecto. Cuando hago Publish no se me están aplicando los cambios.

Básicamente, tengo un `Modal` y quiero que cuando se vea en un monitor tenga un `max-width` de `400px`, y cuando se vea en una pantalla de notebook que tenga un `max-width` de `280px`.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDownload" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
</div>


.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px){
    .modal-content{
        max-width: 280px;
    }

    #btnDownload {
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    }
```

Lo que me está pasando es que no se me está aplicando el cambio del `@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px)`.

Así me queda el `Modal` en la notebook cuando lo ejecuto localmente/debug:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así me queda el `Modal` en la notebook cuando lo Publico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que se haya entendido con las imágenes y si es posible ayudar con esto. Estoy usando Visual Studio 2022, SO Windows 11.

Comment: probaste buscar algun reset.css por internet y agregarlo al principio de tu codigo CSS?  Sirven para formatear estilos generales para evitar este tipo de diferencias entre navegadores, entre otras cosas

Comment: Desconocia eso, me fijo y te digo si se soluciono